# What is the relationship between speaker volume change and resistance change?

Tags: potentiometer, speakers, linear

Assume that we have a speaker whose volume is controlled by the potentiometer. If the resistance of the potentiometer changes by X%, and speaker volume changes by Y%, what is the ideal relationship between the changes?
Y=C.X, is C = 1 or can it be anything?

Comment: Percentage is not a useful unit for such things.  It would make sense to look first at concepts such as decibels, audio taper potentiometers, and then to ask if the potentiometer is actually in the same circuit as the speaker (inline headphone cable, etc) or in the conceptually cleaner role of governing the behavior of or input to an amplifier which drives only the speaker.

Comment: @ChrisStratton
I understand. I want to explain it to people who are new to EE major and just learning about resistors. I wanted to use an actual example of how variable resistor works.

Comment: Generally, explaining the principles is better left to those *answering* the question.  Your question isn't a very good "example of how variable resistor works" because it actually involves quite a bit of unanticipated complexity, a key piece of missing information, and yes, a non-linear need.  Something like a voltage divider or a resistor and an ammeter would be a good example of how variable resistors actually work.

Answer (score 1):

Guess  you have a source, a resistance (assume Ri is your poti) and a load resistor

[image: circuit]

So let us assume the load is variable (multiples of Ri) and the Ri is const, let us plot voltage and current at the load [voltage blue, current red]

[image: voltage_current_Ri]

let us also plot Power and efficiency factor at the load [Power blue, efficiency factor red]

[image]

we can see the following

- max. Power at load is at 50% efficiency
- Power and efficiency cross at 75% when Load is 3 times Ri
- when the ratio RL/Ri is big (>1), the efficiency is good

---

Edit: given the load is a speaker, volume of the speaker is proportional to the voltage

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. When you say proportional, does it have a clear trend?

Comment: No, "volume" in the usual human meaning of the world is *not* proportional to voltage.

Comment: @Shabnam higher Amplitude will cause the speaker to move the membran further which the ear will recognize in a louder sound. As all components do not have a flat frequency response, the ratio will vary over frequency

Comment: @ChrisStratton If you think something is wrong (And I have used that simplified declaration, as any more elaborate dissertation would not add any insight to answer the OPs question), it would be nice if you supply a correction instead of just dropping a opinion

Answer (score 0):

If the relationship between X and Y is linear, one can say that Y=C.X+D, where C is a coefficient and D is an offset. In this case, C=delta(Y)/delta(X). which is equivalent to C=Y%/X% and NOT 1.

But the above is based on the assumption that the system is linear which may not be true in your case.

Comment: I am assuming a linear system for now. Just want to show the application of the variable resistor with the speaker.

Comment: A useful volume control is *not* linear, because "volume" is not linear.